# Xubuntu Application Menu Not Refreshing

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

When a new program gets installed, the item is in the edit menu area, but does not show up in the applications menu.  This is fixed if I close my session of xfce and log back in, but it seems unpredictable as to why it happens or when it happens.

I have tried a couple of ways of manually refreshing, neither seems to work.

Additional Information:

If I right click on desktop, under applications the menu entries are there, so its just on the top bar menu.

Comment: At the very least please provide your Ubuntu and Xfce version. I'm using 4.10 and I don't see this issue; whenver I install a new app, I need to wait for a couple of seconds then the new item is in the menu. Alternatively, maybe you'd have better luck with [xfce4-whiskermenu](http://gottcode.org/xfce4-whiskermenu-plugin/).